# New Laravel app slow pageloading

Tags: laravel-5

I literally have just created a Laravel app and i didn't make a single change ( besides adding the `make:auth` ) and seconds after serving the app it take infinite time to load another view or refresh.

Comment: You may want to include some extra details in your post like how are you running laravel? in a virtual machine? What OS? also importantly what version of laravel and php? Just a shot in the dark but you could try running 'php artisan optimize'. You may also want to try disabling xdebug. 'phpdismod xdebug'

Comment: Oups sorry, i run the app on windows using `php artisan serve`, i'm using php 7.2.4 and laravel 5.6.34
when i try `php artisan optimize` i get that the command is not defined

Comment: did you check your network in inspect element ? and what command did you use to create laravel project ? I always use this composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project_name

Comment: i use that same command for creating a project... any action i do i get 'pending' on Time column on Network and it stays forever